# Facebook like button implementation in android

Tags: android, facebook

I know this question has been asked so many times.

In my app I also want to integrate Facebook like button,after doing lots of R&D I came across the below link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes

and I am using the below code in my app,

```
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("object", "http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791");

   Request request = new Request(
   Session.getActiveSession(),
   "me/og.likes",
   params,
   HttpMethod.POST
  );
  Response response = request.executeAndWait();
 // handle the response
```

but when I click the like button nothing is happening.

Could you all please guide me how to use the above code.

One more thing an extra permission is needed for implementing the above code "Permission: publish_actions".How to get this permission?

Comment: Did you got thing or not..???

Comment: No, do you know how to do it?

Comment: check this post, there is well-formed library to solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853937/1891118

Answer (score 0):

First open session with publish permission using [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session/#openForPublish%28OpenRequest%29)